# Using simple_list_item_activated_1 in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to set up a two fragments view in a XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <fragment android:name="com.delta.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/simple_list_item_activated_1"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.delta.fragments.ArticleFragment"
        android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        tools:layout="@layout/article_fragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that @layout/simple_list_item_activated_1 is being showed in red.

The Java part is the folowing:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1;
String[] data = Ipsum.Headlines;

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),layout,data));
}
```

Does anyone knows how to correct this?

Comment: Can you add the code of your `simple_list_item_activated_1` please

Comment: @MrMins, the only place that `simple_list_item_activated_1` appears is in the java code snippet for `onActivityCreated`I've put above. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Yes, @Marcellu Silva , add The codes of simple_list_item_activated_1 (The XML file)

Comment: @MrMins, I've already put all the code. The whole XML file is the 1st code shown above and the the java snippet is the 2nd code shown above. There is no code anymore in the project that uses `simple_list_item_activated_1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1`.